# How can i fix wordpress site without ftp login

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, runtime-error, login-script

I am content writer to a website that i do not have any ftp account or other host logins, just login of wp-admin.
While i was looking to integrate a slider plugin, installation of this plugin requires copy some code and adding it to functions.php.
I did that from theme options, but it looks like i did not have permissions to do that so website went down showing some errors like this

> Warning:
>   require(/home4/naimberk/public_html/xxxx.com/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/option-tree/ot-loader.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home4/naimberk/public_html/xxx.com/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/functions.php
>   on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   '/home4/naimberk/public_html/xxx.com/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/option-tree/ot-loader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in
>   /home4/naimberk/public_html/xxx.com/wp-content/themes/food-recipes/functions.php
>   on line 11

I do not have ftp accounts either host logins and also i can not have it for some management reasons. What should i do to get my website back ?

Comment: ot-loader.php is not present in your theme folder make sure that file present error will be solved....you need to upload that file.Only from admin you will have the edit option.not for all users.

Comment: you cant do any changes without admin previleges

Answer (score 0):

You have not made it clear if you own the site or just write for them.

If you are not the owner, you will need to contact the owner and explain the issue. If they are not able to sort the issue themselves, the simplest  solution would be to get the owner to contact the hosting company and see if they can rollback the site to before the issue occured.

If you are the owner, you will need top contact the hosting company directly.

There is no way you can repair the issue without FTP access.